# How can I scrape or extract facebook page reviews?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, review

I am looking for extracting facebook page reviews but unable to do it with graph API, it allows a lot of other things to be extracted but not reviews.
If someone could help with this issue.

Comment: It allows to get reviews, if you have admin access to the page. Otherwise, the reviews are none of your business. (And scraping is not allowed.)

Comment: Okay, I am admin of the page how can I access reviews?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

Comment: It would only return rating, I need complete reviews.

Comment: No, it would not return the rating only. It clearly states that you get a list of OpenGraphRating nodes back, and what fields those have, you find here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/open-graph-rating/

Answer (score 1):

There are some external services that can get facebook reviews for you: a couple of examples are https://wextractor.com/facebook and https://www.reviewshake.com/review-scraper-api/scrape-facebook-reviews